# I can't upload image in python selenium form

Tags: python

I'm sure I'm requesting to the right place, the image is not uploading, the operation is waiting without error

macOSS
Chrome
Python 3.8
Selenium

```
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@jscontroller="soHxf"]')[1].send_keys("./img1.jpg")
            sleep(2)
```

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxonO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/972z6.png)

https://www.google.com/local/place/rap/addaplace?isEmbedded=true&hl=en

Comment: Please add more details, not images or links.

Comment: try clicking the attached links